# Site says I can use chat, but I still get the banner saying I need rep >= 20

Tags: discussion

I can go to my account info and see that I earned the priviledge to use chat.  But one of my threads was moved to chat and I can't use it.  There's still a banner at the bottom saying I need a rep of at least 20.  I have a green square showing +31.  My profile has a 36 then "*6" next to it.  There's no explanation for those.

Comment: It can take a little bit to update. Try clearing your cache and reloading the page.

Comment: Thank you, Seth.  I did it, (and it's been four days already).  Still the same though.

Comment: Your chat profile shows 36 rep. Are you sure it still doesn't work? Try clearing your cookies and logging back in.